# JFace: Expand more levels for specific nodes

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, treeviewer, treelistview

when the user expands specific nodes in my TreeViewer, it should expand two levels instead of one. So I added the following code:

```
viewer.addTreeListener(new ITreeViewerListener() {
            public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            }

            public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
                if (event.getElement() instanceof Feature) {
                    Feature feature = (Feature) event.getElement();
                    viewer.expandToLevel(feature, 2);
                }
            }
        });
```

but I only get this error message when expanding Feature nodes:

```
!MESSAGE Ignored reentrant call while viewer is busy. This is only logged once per viewer instance, but similar calls will still be ignored.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.checkBusy(ColumnViewer.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.expandToLevel(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1071)
...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to solve it in another way?

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call view methods like `expandToLevel` in the listener because the viewer is already dealing with an expand and is not designed to deal with another expand while it is doing that.

You could use `Display.asyncExec` in the `treeExpanded` method to run the `expandToLevel` after the expand current has completed.